# PHP multiple $_GET

Tags: php, html, database, post, get

I am using checkboxes to let people select what they want to delete from database, it can happen that they decide to delete more things at once and if they do my link looks like :

```
?delete=24&delete=11
```

my HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type='checkbox' name='delete' value=" . $row['server_id'] . ">
</form>
```

What i need to do with it is to delete 1 line from SQL

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id=$server_id & name= $name, $con
```

If it will be just 1 variable I will easy just GET it but right now I am not sure how to do it, can somebody help me please?

Comment: For INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE database queries, never use a GET request, always a POST request. If you did this already with GET requests earlier, you need to fix your existing code first before worrying about multiple values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use with `[]` on URL

```
?delete[]=24&delete[]=11
```

Use form input like:

```
name='delete[]'
```

#### For Example:

```
$ids = $_GET['delete'];

foreach ($ids as $id)
{
   // DELETE FROM TABLE
}
```

#### Alternative

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
   if (!is_array($_GET['delete']))
      $ids = array((int)($_GET['delete']));
   else
      $ids = array_map('intval', $_GET['delete']);

   $ids = implode(",", $ids);    
   $sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN ({$ids})";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming here and trying o help me but to say true i am not sure how this can help me solve my issue

Comment: c'mon boys, do a foreach to fire multiple database queries for the delete operation? really?

Comment: `"DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $_GET['delete']) . ") AND name = $name"`. **Don't forget to escape user input sent to the database!**

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: You mean *forgetting* like you did? :) `$deleteIds = array_map('intval', isset($_GET['delete']) ? (array) $_GET['delete'] : []);`

Comment: @hakre `"DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', array_walk($_GET['delete'], function (&$v) { $v = database_escape_string($v); })) . ") AND name = '" . database_escape_string($name) . "'"`

Comment: @bora: Don't operate on `$_GET` directly when creating a sql query. Convert all those to integers first. Also only fire the query when at least one id is the (the array is boolean true).

Comment: But all this is not the biggest problem. Never (***NEVER***) run a delete query on GET requests.

Comment: Guys my problem is that if i put name as delete[] url looks like ?delete%5B%5D=11&delete%5B%5D=24 so it replace [ and ]with other chars

Comment: i found them here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp so idk how script read it

Answer (score 1):

Use [] after the name:

```
<form>
<input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' value=" . $row['server_id'] . "> 
...
</form>
```

That would send ?delete[]=24&delete[]=11

PHP would then translate it into an array.

```
$delete_ids = isset($_REQUEST['delete']) ? (array) $_REQUEST['delete'] : array();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it more fancy but a bit more complex, you can also do this:

```
?delete=1,2,3,4
```

With the code being:

```
$arr = explode(',', $_GET['delete']);
print_r($arr);
```

This wouldn't exactly be good for forum input (because its never seen) but if the user ever needs to look at or change the url it would be easier to read.

Comment: And how do you send as GET from a form with `1,2,3,4` id's ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga yea thats a good point, I just wanted to point out theres another way if the checkboxes are being parsed with javascript or something.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem you can specify  form method as POST

e.g

```
    <form method="POST">
          <input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' value=" . $row['server_id'] . "> 
    </form>
```

On server side you can access the value of form field using $_POST superglobal variable.